# Is it advisable to build a new app for iOS 5 specifically now - What's the install base like?

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I'm about to start a new project which will take 6 weeks or so.  There are lots of tableviews in this project, and most of them would take advantage of custom prototype cells and static layout tableviews.

Given I will have so many, I'm wondering if I should go down the path of doing iOS 5 only, therefore I can use Storyboarding and get the new tableview goodness.

What are your thoughts on going a iOS 5 only app now, or should I be waiting for the install base to increase?

Comment: "What are your thoughts..." is an invitation for discussion and argument, which means this is not a good question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is 'would it be better practice to use iOS 5 given the user base at the moment' - I'd have to answer that there are a number of trains of thought on this.  The first is that as with all new iOS versions, it's gonna take a bit of time for people to get up to the latest.  The other is that if someone wants your app enough, they will get their device upgraded (assuming there isn't an alternative).

My developer buddies are always telling me I should just jump to the latest version because from the developer point of view, it makes no sense in starting on an old version.  I used to support iOS going back to version 3.1 - but it's getting harder to do that these days.

If it were me, I'd give the customer the choice and say you can have older support but it will cost you more money, or you can have latest support and it will be less.